# LinkButton to create Email in Outlook

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

I have a LinkButton with text showing an email pulled from a DB.  I want to OnClick to Create New Email in Outlook and put this LinkButton text in the TO section and then prefilled the subject.  The code works as long as I manually type in the email but when I tell it to read the LinkButton.text, it does nothing.  Doesn't even open Outlook.

This WORKS --

```
EmailLB.OnClientClick = "window.location.href = 'mailto:someone@something.com?subject=MD Judicial Insurance Plan';"
```

This DOES NOT --

```
EmailLB.OnClientClick = "window.location.href = 'mailto:'" & EmailLB.Text & "'?subject=MD Judicial Insurance Plan';"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra single quote between EmailLB.Text and ?subject. remove that single quote
Try Like

```
EmailLB.OnClientClick = "window.location.href = 'mailto:" & EmailLB.Text & "?subject=MD Judicial Insurance Plan';"
```

Comment: EmailLB.OnClientClick = "window.location.href = 'mailto:'" & EmailLB.Text & "?subject=MD Judicial Insurance Plan';"

Comment: please show the result of `EmailLB.OnClientClick = "window.location.href = 'mailto:'" & EmailLB.Text & "'?subject=MD Judicial Insurance Plan';"`

Comment: `EmailLB.OnClientClick = "window.location.href = 'mailto:" & EmailLB.Text & "?subject=MD Judicial Insurance Plan';"` this looks better

Answer (score 0):

That worked!  Thanks!

EmailLB.OnClientClick = "window.location.href = 'mailto:" & EmailLB.Text & "?subject=MD Judicial Insurance Plan';"